# Add DOM element then remove it

Tags: jquery

I need to add a child div inside a parent div and then delete the child div in x sec.

There could be several children divs added to parent div.

What would the best way to identify and delete the child div?

```
$("#parent_div").prepend("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By keeping a reference to it:

```
function doTheChildDivThing() {
    var child = $("<div>" + msg + "</div>");
    $("#parent").prepend(child);
    setTimeout(function() {
        child.remove();
    }, 1000);
}
```

---

Re your comment below:

> why delay() (instead of setTimeout) is not working in that case?

[`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) works with the effects queue. `remove` isn't an effects-related method. You could certainly use `delay` with one of the [effects methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/), though, like `slideUp`. Then you'd remove the child within the completion callback of the effects method, like this:

```
function doTheChildDivThing() {
    var child = $("<div>" + msg + "</div>");
    $("#parent").prepend(child);
    child.delay(1000).slideUp(function() {
        child.remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, +1 (for being right), but that function name? Sounds like a terrible eighties party hit...

Comment: +1, I have no idea what exactly he was asking, but it looks like it can be it.

Comment: why delay() (instead of setTimeout) is not working in that case?

Comment: @ihtus: `delay` is only for use with effects-related messages, I've updated the answer with some information on how you could use it for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$("<div/>", {

  // PROPERTIES HERE

  text: "Click me",

  id: "example",

  "class": "myDiv",      // ('class' is still better in quotes)

  css: {           
     color: "red",
     fontSize: "3em",
     cursor: "pointer"
  },

  on: {
    mouseenter: function() {
      console.log("PLEASE... "+ $(this).text());
    },
    click: function() {
      console.log("Hy! My ID is: "+ this.id);
    }
  },

  append: "<i>!!</i>",

  appendTo: "body"      // Finally, append to any selector

}); 

// And remove 

setTimeout(() => {
    $('.myDiv').remove();
}, 1000)
```